# SharePoint Online Connectors not working and now missing

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, office-365, webhooks, jira

I'm using SharePoint online, Plan 1 with modern Team sites and Communication sites.  I was having an issue adding any connector, I could add the connector but when I clicked on "configure connector", I would get a "Something went wrong" error with a sad face.  I've tried creating new site collections, tried different site templates, tried all the web connectors I could find, and still the same error.  I'm particularly interested in the Jira and Webhooks connectors but also tried Asana and several other.  I have also noticed the same error when using Yammer connectors however unsure if related.

After a lengthy email exchange with Office 365 support, I find that connectors are no longer available to me and now missing.  I also received an email stating the following:

> After some consultation and research, we're very sorry to inform you
>   that the issue seems to be a bit out of scope and we don't have a
>   specialist to help you out either, however, below, I've attached a
>   link which takes you to our solution providers for SharePoint. There
>   are a few solution providers, who should be able to help you, and
>   please choose the one that fits your issue. Type SharePoint on the
>   search section. The support on that platform is paid support, and not
>   free like ours.

Has anyone else run across issues with the Connectors?   I'm tempted to go back to the "classic" site but was really liking the modern web parts and connectors.   I'm surprised it's not more functional by now.

Comment: You don't need to go to classic to use old style workflows, You can start them from the modern experience now. (under more in item menu)

Comment: @MarekSarad - I'm more interested in the web parts / connectors at the moment, not the workflows.